# How Do i make my services registered to consul communicate with each other?

Tags: service-discovery, consul

Working on POC for Consul

Lets  say I have consul agent running as server and i have registered two services
(Service1 , Service2 ) , which are API , so how service1 and service2 will communicate ?

Comment: you could query the consul agent to get the address and port, or you could use the dns functionality

Comment: @Bor Do you mean that i should use consul api to query and get host port ?

Comment: yes, using your local consul agent, or use DNS to get an SRV record.

Comment: @Bor i think wat you are saying is about how i personal can view services detail, what i really want is  how my service will do that by dns lets say if i do **curl -XGET http://web.service.consul/test/test.txt** i sud be getting test.txt from any one of the service

Comment: @Bor can u tell me any example where i can get how i can retrieve host port of service and use it in my api to access service?

Comment: aha, i understand what you want now i think :) . Take a look at consul-template, you can use it to rewrite the config of a proxy server (e.g. haproxy). If i find the time i will supply you with a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

On this example I assume service1 depends on service2, and service2 has registed itself to Consul. You can simply use the [HTTP Catalog API](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/catalog.html#catalog_service) to query Consul which ip + port combinations provide service2. Without load-balancing it is service1's responsibility to implement it, handle failure cases and so forth.

A more "advanced" option is to use Consul to generate a config for a load balancer, this way service1 can use a hard-coded ip or domain name to contact the load balancer and will will forward the traffic to a healthy instance of service2.